# Magento 2 Cart and Search Shifts in Safari when Mini Cart Expanded

Tags: magento2, css

Using the default Luma theme the search and cart icon shift over to the left when the mini cart is expanded when using Safari on Ipads and Macbooks.

I have been trying various CSS to fix however typing anything within inspect element in Safari seems to fix issue making it difficult to debug. So far however setting the width of .minicart-wrapper to 52px seems to fix however still doesn't look perfect.

This looks a bit messy and i was hoping someone has also experienced this and found a fix?

[image]

Comment: does it work for you

Comment: Yeah it worked i think i never set as answer as i had already said your answer in my question  as my workaround. It does work tho and have nothing better so will set answer.

Comment: it sounds great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this update this class .minicart-wrapper , define width for div containing this class

div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper"> for example assign 50px width